# How to add OnClickListener for grid view which opens new activity?

Tags: java, android, gridview, onclicklistener

I have added OnCLickListener for gridview, but it is returning error.
Where i am doing wrong.
I have used intents to handle this Listener.

Activity.java

```
public class AlbumsActivity extends Fragment{

    public AlbumsActivity() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams") ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, null);
        GridView gridView=(GridView)root.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Intent is what you use to start another activity
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlayingActivity.class);
                startActivity(Intent);
            }

        });
        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: update your code and give us more information

Comment: I have edited the changes in code. It is showing error for line of code telling expression expexted                                                          
startActivity(Intent);

Comment: is not Intent, you must use the object :
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlayingActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

Comment: Thanks.I fixed it , but app is crashing now.

Comment: Probably your NowPlayingActivity activity is not declared in your AndroidManifest

Comment: It is declared.

Comment: put the log here in  your answer

Answer (score 2):

Fix this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlayingActivity.class);
startActivity(Intent);
```

Change to:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlayingActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `gridView.setOnItemClickListener` method instead of `setOnClickListener`.

Also, please add error details (stacktrace) in future posts.

Comment: I have implemented code as you said , some part of error has fixed. But now it is showing error for code startActivity(Intent);

Answer (score 1):

You should use "myIntent"

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NowPlayingActivity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```